# Getting the least possible order of a group from existing cyclic subgroups or elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let's say I have finite group $G$. Let it have have following subgroups:

$<a> = \{e, a\}$,
$<b> = \{e, b\}$,
$<c> = \{e, c, c^2\}$,
$<d> = \{e, d, d^2, d^3\}$

I can for sure say that $ad, ad^2, ad^3$ are distinct.

Can I say that $bc$ is distinct too?

Or can I say the same about $bd, bd^2, bd^3$?

What is the least possible order of $G$ in this case?

also

I want to make this as general as possible, so how can we get new distinct elements if we know some of them?

Comment: It depends partly on the assumptions you make about $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$. For example, is $b = d^2$ permitted? You need to spell out what is assumed distinct.

Comment: You can just add in extra stuff to make the group bigger, so there's no limit on the order. You seem to have omitted or missed the importance of a number of assumptions.